# Multiplying Bacteria

Tags: sequences-and-series

The population of bacteria double every 30mins. The initial population of the bacteria is 100, What is the population after 6hrs and 12 hrs. How do I answer this?

Answer (score 1):

1. How many bacteria are there after 30 minutes?
2. How many bacteria are there after 60 minutes?
3. How many bacteria are there after 90 minutes?
4. …

Comment: 1. $100(2)$ 2. $100(2)^2$ 3. $100(2)^3$ ? so for 6 hours is it $100(2)^{12}$?

Comment: I was thinking if there's a formula for population growth where I can just substitute?

Comment: Your answer is correct! Didn't you just figure out, and tell me, the formula for population growth?

Comment: @Mickey Think about how you obtained the $12$.  What would the exponent be if $t = 12~\text{h}$?  What would you obtain after $t$ hours?